# How to turn off LTE data connection programmatically in android 6 and android 7?

Tags: android-wifi, android-networking, android-7.0-nougat, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I want to reach a router this way:

`isReachable = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1").isReachable(2000);`

But it returns false.

Curiously when I turn off LTE data manually it works.

I found this code to turn on/off LTE data programmatically but it does not work on android 6 or 7.

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) 
{
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)    
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)   
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = 
    conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  
    Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = 
    iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", 
    Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

Could you help to find an other way to turn on/off LTE data on android 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

I found how to resolve my problem. i fail to turn off cellular data programmatically, but  if found a way to force my app to use only wifi connection . this is the code:

```
final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager  = 
(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkRequest.Builder request = null;
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=                                          
android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

        request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            //if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP && SDK_INT <= M) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
            }

            }
    });
    }
```